# awk fetching specific line and specific field

Tags: awk, row, line

I need some help with awk. My aim is to fetch in a bunge of lines the seventh line and within that seventh line the fifth field. 
After reading some manuals about awk, I decided to do it like this, without having the result I wanted. 
Any hint would be great. Thanks in advance.

```
awk {OFS=":"};{if (NR == 8) {print $5} else if (NR == 7) {print $5} } ;
```

Comment: What result did you get?

Comment: `OFS` is output field separator. You probably want to specify `FS`  instead, which is input field separator.

Comment: MY first version said "unexpected syntaxerror `NR'  ", so NR was unknown, in a certain way. The first suggestion maid here sounds good indeed, but as always some tiny detail in my specific line has to change. But thanks a lot so far. BTW I wanted output field separator as by default there is space as field separator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may be some like this you want:

```
awk -F: 'NR==7 || NR==8 {print $5}' file
```

It will print the fifth field of line `7` and `8`

Can also be written:

```
awk  -F:  'NR~/^(7|8)$/ {print $5}' file
```

Comment: Man, this one looks even smarter, though I'd need some explanation for the /^, that means the first digit, and the $ probably means the row? I just guess that is what it means.

Comment: @Andrew `^` means start of some, and `$` end of some. In this case start and end of `NR`. Since I use `~` (does contain), I need to set border. Eks `NR=="7"` gives only `NR` equal `7` while `NR~/7/` will hit on `7` `17``5764` etc, while `NR~/^7$/` only hits on `7`

Comment: Thanks a lot, that is compelling.